# How to set the background of color-hex-values with corresponding color in all modes (like in css-mode)?

Tags: colors, coloring, css, style

In css-mode color strings get a background color corresponding to the respective color - like this (image):

[image: css-color-string-coloring]

How to achieve this behaviour in other modes?

Answer (score 1):

OK… wasn't aware of rainbow-mode, wich does exactly, what I intended. Of cource I found it *after* I posted question here ^^.

So the solution is:

> M-x package-install RET rainbow-mode RET

To answer my question completely and enable it in *all* modes: I added

> (define-globalized-minor-mode global-rainbow-mode rainbow-mode
>    (lambda () (rainbow-mode 1)))
>
> (global-rainbow-mode 1)

to my init file.